# trying to work with group but need to get previous pipe data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to find the phone numbers that are existed and if existed then provide me their ids with phone number as well as the phone numbers which don't exist. The input i receive only the array of phone numbers which i need to check against the database to figure out which one exist and which ones not as shown in the bottom of this post.

User data

```
{
    "_id" : "mJPqhyyGoeyfa3p2w",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-11-30T22:33:27.649Z"),
    "phone" : {
        "number" : "123456789",
        "verified" : true
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "dsfsyGoeyfa3p2w",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-11-30T22:33:27.649Z"),
    "phone" : {
        "number" : "+14155553695",
        "verified" : true
    }
}
```

So far tried with following query, given the input `[ "123456789", "+14155553695", 10, 20]`

```
db.users.aggregate([
{ 
    '$match': { "phone.number" : { '$in' : [ "123456789", "+14155553695", 10, 20]}}
}
,{ 
    '$project' : {"phone" : "$phone.number"},
}
,{ 
    '$group' : {
    "_id" : null, 
    'phones': {'$push' : '$phone'}
    }
}
])
```

Trying to achieve below first

```
{  
   "result":[  
      {  
         "_id":null,
         "phones":[  
            "+14155553695",
            "123456789"
         ],
         phoneFoundDetails:[  
            {  
               "_id":"xsLSt8cNaggcirxGu",
               "phone":"+14155553695"
            },
            {  
               "_id":"mJPqhyyGoeyfa3p2w",
               "phone":"123456789"
            }
         ],
         "ok":1.0000000000000000
      }
   ]
}
```

And eventually achieve something like this

```
{  
   "result":[  
      {  
         "_id":null,
         "notFound":[  
            "10",
            "20"
         ],
         phoneFoundDetails:[  
            {  
               "_id":"xsLSt8cNaggcirxGu",
               "phone":"+14155553695"
            },
            {  
               "_id":"mJPqhyyGoeyfa3p2w",
               "phone":"123456789"
            }
         ],
         "ok":1.0000000000000000
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you retrieve all those that are found and then do a post result operation to list those that weren't found in the client? Doing all of this would be difficult to do in one query

Comment: I think that make sense as well. Can i get phones and phoneFoundDetails in same result set?

Comment: @inspired I commented about using $match, is it recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this to get your desired result:

```
db.phones.aggregate([
  {"$match": { "phone.number" : { "$in" : [ "123456789", "+14155553695", 10, 20]}}},
  {'$group' : {
    "_id" : null,
    "phones": { "$push" : "$phone.number"},
    "phoneFoundDetails": {"$push" : {"_id":"$_id" , "phone" : "$phone.number"}}}
  }
])
```

According to your sample data it would return:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "phones" : [
        "123456789",
        "+14155553695"
    ],
    "phoneFoundDetails" : [
        {
            "_id" : "mJPqhyyGoeyfa3p2w",
            "phone" : "123456789"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "dsfsyGoeyfa3p2w",
            "phone" : "+14155553695"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So to get the one i wanted, i just need to  add following at the end of aggregation {
    '$project' : {
        'notFound' : {
            '$setDifference' : [ [ "123456789", "+14155553695", 10, 20], '$phones']
        },
        'phoneFoundDetails' : 1}
        
}

Comment: Can you edit your answer with my change? May be correct it if i was doing in wrong way.

Comment: By the way should i use $match first to filter the data with phone number that are interested so i don't consume lot of memory  if the data set becomes really large?

Comment: @user1595858 the first match statement does a large filter for you